# Node.js - Unity, Socket gets disconnected after getting re-connected

Tags: node.js, sockets, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a Node.js - Unity game where I'm using sockets, for users to get connect to the game. I getting an issue, like its getting reconnected-disconnected like a loop in the unity. But when I checked through the web browser I'm not getting such problem. 
One more thing recently I was using one port(3011) - here its working fine and after shifting to a different port (3012 not working correctly). I thought this the case but it's not.

I'm using node version v6.11.0 (with port 3011 and 3012) and
socket version 2.0.3 for node.js(server side)

Can anyone help me?
This the sample code

```
io.on('connection', function(socket)
{
  console.log('User connected');

  socket.on('disconnect', function(reason){
    console.log('User disconnected',reason);
  });
});

socket.on('joinroom', function(roomId)
{
  console.log('player joined room: ' + roomId);
  socket.join("room_"+roomId);
});

http.listen(3012, function(){
  console.log('Started nodejs server');
  initRoomActivity();
});
```

the issue looks like

```
player joined room: XXXX
User disconnected client namespace disconnect
User connected
player joined room: XXXX
User disconnected client namespace disconnect
User connected
player joined room: XXXX
```

here XXXX refers to the same room,
here "client namespace disconnect" is the disconnect reason

Comment: i had exactly the same issue recently, i'm using BestHTTP Pro for socket.io in unity, updating it to the latest version solved it for me.

Comment: @turnipinrut, thanks, let me check

Comment: can we do this without updating, any other way?

Comment: maybe use an older version of the websocket lib

Comment: okay, let me check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using npm libraries ?
If yes then you might have upgraded the socket.io npm package

If yes then try to downgrade it and try once again 
Don't try to upgrade the packages that are used in the current project

Answer (score 0):

Set `c#` `socketOption` to 700

```
TimeSpan miliSecForReconnect = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(700);
```

Change your `server.js` as

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http, { pingInterval: 700 });
```

Add this ping interval